# What are the main differences between Babel and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I know that TypeScript was used to write Angular2, which probably makes it a better choice for someone who wants to get into Angular2, but when I look at Babel it looks very much like TypeScript.

I noticed that many well known companies stick to Babel.

Some questions:

1. What advantages do they have over each other?
2. Which make them better or worse choice for the project/developer?
3. What are the major differences between them and what make them unique?

Comment: Even at a glance it's clear they are completely different tools. You can answer this question by investing 15 minutes into the intro for each.

Comment: TypeScript is a language, Babel is a tool (to transpile ES6, a language, to ES5).

Comment: @Marty The two compilers are competing, this question is legitimate.

Comment: @Paleo That seems unusual, from what I can see they have very different offerings and goals.

Comment: They are used to do the same thing: applications for the browser or for Node.js. Teams arriving newly in the field are all facing this question: Which tool best fits their need?

Comment: Here is a detailed answer from typescript team: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/babel-with-typescript.html - tl;dr `Do you need a build pipeline with multiple potential outputs? Use babel for transpiling and tsc for type checking`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a superset of JavaScript that compiles down into plain JavaScript (ES3+). The main goal of TypeScript is to enable developers to leverage excellent static typing capabilities. It is suitable for large applications that would benefit from features like:

- Type annotations & type inference.
- Generics.
- Interfaces, enums, namespaces, modules and classes (the latter two available in ES6).
- Safe refactoring.

As far as I am aware, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) simply "transpiles" newer ECMAScript features down into a format that is supported by older ECMAScript environments. It is suitable for developers who want to write plain JavaScript using newer language features.

Comment: does that mean TypeScript is both a ES6 to ES3+ transpiler and a  superset of javascript that it adds somewhat capabilities to javascript,whereas Bable only transpiles ES6 to ES5?

Comment: And now Typescript supports plain old Javascript, so there is really NO REASON to use babel any more.

Comment: @Marty: I want to complain about "is a superset of JavaScript". No, it's not. There's plenty of valid JavaScript that isn't valid TypeScript. TypeScript is a Super & Subset of JavaScript, all at the same time.

Comment: @StefanSteiger That remark is from TypeScript's introduction of itself (literally the 2nd line on their homepage), not any special analysis that I have done myself on what I think it is.

Comment: @StefanSteiger It is indeed a superset, not a subset. The examples you're referring to of valid JavaScript that is not valid TypeScript are due to the default TS compiler options (which most people use). You can loosen the restrictions in the compiler settings so that _any_ valid JavaScript will compile, but you will lose some of the guard rails that encourage Better™ code

Answer (score 30):

Victor Savkin one of angular 2 developers talks why they selected Typescript over other technologies.

http://victorsavkin.com/post/123555572351/writing-angular-2-in-typescript

the last section 
**Why Typescript?**

"There are a lot of options available to frontend devs today: ES5, ES6 (Babel), TypeScript, Dart, PureScript, Elm, etc.. So why TypeScript?

Let’s start with ES5. ES5 has one significant advantage over TypeScript: it does not require a transpiler. This allows you to keep your build setup simple. You do not need to set up file watchers, transpile code, generate source maps. It just works. For many small projects this simplicity outweighs the advanced refactoring and navigation capabilities TypeScript provides. You just know where all the code is, and what it does.

ES6 requires a transpiler, so the build setup will not much different from TypeScript. But it is a standard, which means that every single editor and build tool either supports ES6 or will support it.

Elm and PureScript are elegant languages with powerful type systems that can prove a lot more about your program than TypeScript can. The code written in Elm and PureScript can be a lot terser than similar code written in ES5.

Each of these options has pros and cons, but I think TypeScript is in a sweet spot that makes it a great choice for most projects. TypeScript takes 95% of the usefulness of a good statically-typed language and brings it to the JavaScript ecosystem. You still feel like you write ES6: you keep using the same standard library, same third-party libraries, same idioms, and many of the same tools (e.g., Chrome dev tools). It gives you a lot without forcing you out of the JavaScript ecosystem."

Comment: Late 2019 checking in. Nowadays, if you have some say over your user base's browser choice — most notably, if you don't care about IE support — then ES6 by and large no longer requires a compiler.